# "Gravitate" vs "be attracted"

Tags: verbs, verb-forms

I was wondering if someone could help me and let me know which verb in my self-made sentence bellow would sound idiomatically natural in English:

- They **gravitated** to each other at the first sight.
- They **were attracted** to each other at the first sight.

**Note:** By 'they" I mean a lover and beloved. (A couple who are in a deep love at the moment.)

Comment: Who are "they"? If you meant *love at first sight*, then definitely *attract* is better. BTW, *the* should be omitted.

Answer (score 1):

As with many English words, "gravitate" has a kind of *literal* definition that can be figuratively applied to make a sentence more picturesque:

> [grav·i·tate: Move, or tend to move, towards a centre of gravity or other attractive force.](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/gravitate)

So imagine two planets slowly drawn toward each other.  That's what I see when I hear the word "gravitate".  Meanwhile, "attract" is like two magnets that experience a pull toward each other.  If they are held in place, they don't actually *move* but nevertheless the force exists between them.

> They gravitated toward each other at first sight.
>
> They were attracted to each other at first sight

The two are close but not perfect synonyms. "Gravitate" implies *motion*, while "attract" only implies *force*.  Which of these two you want to use depends entirely on what you want to say.

Comment: Gravitate also has a proper definition (by Google) as : 
"move towards or be attracted to a person or thing.
"young western Europeans will gravitate to Berlin" . 
In this case , even that's appropriate to the sentence isn't it?

Comment: @Andrew Could you please edit your answer to tell us where the definition comes from?  Thank you.

Comment: @VanpramP since "gravitate" derives from "gravity", it's impossible to use the word figuratively without the image of a gravitational force at work.  Many English words are like this -- for example, "He showered her with gifts," means, "He gave her lots of gifts," but inherent to the phrase is the image of an actual shower head (or rain shower) with gifts coming out of it.  If you're going to use a word in creative writing, you really should know the derivation of a word as well as its dictionary definition. Otherwise it's easy to misuse the word in an inappropriate context.

Comment: @snailplane done, linked to Oxford English Dictionary and changed spelling to match.